# Why won't my reactjs file correctly display user email address?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, debugging

I want the email to displayed upon user hitting submit.  But I get an error in both localhosts (3000 and htdocs).

Inside localhost 3000, Upon clicking submit, I get redirected to Inside `http://localhost:3000/index.php` with an error that reads: `Cannot POST /index.php`

Inside localhost via htdocs folder, I get an error that says: `Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/src/index.php on line 2`

I'm trying to properly connect php with react.js.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <form action="index.php" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
              <label>Email: </label><input type="email" name="email"/>
              <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
          </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's `index.php`:

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the input data(email) to the index.php and print it just modify the second input field to a button.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
          <label>Email: </label><input type="email" name="email"/>
          <button type="submit" value="upload">Upload</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: As far as I know, `input[type="submit"]` works exactly like `button[type="submit"].

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor{
  this.state = {email: ''}
}

_handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value,
    });
  }

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <label>Email: </label>
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this._handleChange}/>
</form>
```

Hope this will work. 
I have no experience in php but you can get email text box data through state. 
Also, you can submit on form submit and call api or get data.